# How can i send a Pagination-embed with a music list discord.js

Tags: list, pagination, discord.js, embed

I want send in a Pagination-embed with a music list because whan an embed is lower at 1024 letters it doesn't send.
I want send in many pages (4musics max per pages)

Sorry for my english, i'm french...

```
  console.log(_serverQueue.songs)
  let q = ``;
  for(var i = 1; i < _serverQueue.songs.length; i++) {
      q += `\n${i + 1}. **${_serverQueue.songs[i].title}**`;
  }
  let resp = [
      {name: `Now Playing`, value: _serverQueue.songs[0].title},
      {name: `Queue`, value: q},
  ];

  //Putting it all together
  const FieldsEmbed = new Pagination.FieldsEmbed()
  .setArray({word: `Queue`})
  .setAuthorizedUsers([message.author.id])
  .setChannel(message.channel)
  .setElementsPerPage(4)
  .setPageIndicator(true)
  .formatField('Playlist :', el => el.word)
  FieldsEmbed.embed
    .setColor('#008000')
    .setTitle('Playlist :')
    FieldsEmbed.build()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Documentation of https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-paginationembed

I explained the steps with Comments

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Pagination = require('discord-paginationembed');

const songText = ["This is a long SongText", "That is Split up Over", "Multiple Sites", "End of Song"];
// The Splitting can happen via Discord.Js Util Class, it has a Splitter

const embeds = [];
 
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
  embeds.push(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setFooter('Page ' + i).setDescription(songText[i - 1]));
 // Create Embeds here with the Content and push them into the Array

const myImage = message.author.displayAvatarURL();
 
new Pagination.Embeds()
  .setArray(embeds)
  .setAuthorizedUsers([message.author.id])
  .setChannel(message.channel)
  .setPageIndicator(true)
  .setPage(1)
   // Methods below are for customizing all embeds
  .setImage(myImage)
  .setThumbnail(myImage)
  .setTitle('Test Title')
  .setDescription('Test Description')
  .setURL(myImage)
  .setColor(0xFF00AE)
  .build();
```